# Find binary vector furthest away from set of binary vectors?

Tags: optimization, discrete-optimization, non-convex-optimization, binary-programming

How can I find the binary vector furthest away from a set of binary vectors?

Comment: Norm maximization is not a convex problem. You would need to use a nonconvex mixed-integer quadratic solver if you want to follow this path.

Comment: Can you recommend any free software that can do this or possibly an alternative approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $i\in\{1,\dots,n\}$ and $j\in\{1,\dots,d\}$, let $x_{i,j}\in\{0,1\}$ be the given value  of vector $i$, coordinate $j$.  For $j\in\{1,\dots,d\}$, let binary decision variable $y_j$ be coordinate $j$ of the desired vector.  You want to maximize
$$\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^d (x_{i,j} - y_j)^2 = \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^d (x^2_{i,j} - 2 x_{i,j} y_j + y_j^2) = \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^d (x_{i,j} - 2 x_{i,j} y_j + y_j).$$
Equivalently, maximize
$$\sum_{j=1}^d y_j \sum_{i=1}^n (1-2x_{i,j}) = \sum_{j=1}^d y_j \left(n-2\sum_{i=1}^n x_{i,j}\right).$$
So take $y_j=1$ if $\sum_{i=1}^n x_{i,j} < n/2$ and $y_j=0$ otherwise.